# Docker Windows timeout

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure an environment on Windows 10 using `docker` and `docker-compose`, but I am not being able to pull the images from the docker registry.

Everytime I run `docker-compose up -d`, I get the error below:

```
Pulling queue (redis:)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:36785->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout
```

I've looked around online and some people recommended setting the DNS server to a fixed one: `8.8.8.8`. I did this, but I still have the problem.

**UPDATE**

As per @kaki suggestion, I looked at my hosts file and I saw several entries that were regarding docker:

```
100.114.69.30 host.docker.internal
100.114.69.30 gateway.docker.internal
 host.docker.internal
 gateway.docker.internal
 192.168.1.103 host.docker.internal
 192.168.1.103 gateway.docker.internal
# Added by Docker Desktop
 192.168.0.11 host.docker.internal
 192.168.0.11 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I removed all of them but these:

```
100.114.69.30 host.docker.internal
100.114.69.30 gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

and things started working.

Comment: Do you have proxy servers in your network?

Comment: No. I connect directly to the internet.

Comment: I only had the three that you left in the hosts file. I deleted all docker related entries and it resolved this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason your network adapter thinks this domain can be found in your lan, in order to fix this I would try to see whether your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` has been changed to this value (the computer checks the hosts file before querying the dns server).
If this one doesn't solve the problem I would ask the network admin about the issue in case that you are working in an enterprise environment, otherwise if it is private I would check the router settings.

Comment: Hi, I checked my hosts file and it had several entries regarding docker (I don't know where they came from, maybe from the installation). I've edited it and it worked.

Comment: I've updated my question with the contents of the `hosts` file.

Comment: After many days looking for a solution and testing many workaround suggested on forums, this was really my definive solution. Now it is working.

Comment: this saved me from going crazy. was looking a solution for days now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issues. I have tried to remove the below lines from the host file

## Added by Docker Desktop

100.114.69.30 host.docker.internal
100.114.69.30 gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal

## End of section

But still same problem while writing the command line - docker login;  in PowerShell. Then I clean the data using docker desktop troubleshooting option and restart the docker, it's working
[image]

Here is the below PowerShell script

[image]